# Load a .tmx (Tiled Map) in Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Is there a (preferably easy) way to load a .tmx file in iOS 7's Sprite Kit? If not, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out [**TilemapKit**](http://tilemapkit.com) for Sprite Kit. Unlike other solutions it **loads and renders all (!) map types and variations** supported by Tiled, including staggered iso and hex maps!

TilemapKit is properly engineered like a OOP framework should be, and exposes all data that is stored in the TMX file. In other words it's definitely not just a single class that got everything crammed into it.

Tile picking (point to coord, coord to point conversion) for all map types/variations is built-in. More awesome features on the way, [review the roadmap](http://tilemapkit.com/tilemapkit-features/) and check out the [Class Reference](http://tilemapkit.com/class-reference).

TilemapKit is also tested to be **fully compatible with Swift** and Mac apps, too.

Visit the [TilemapKit forum](http://forum.tilemapkit.com) if you have any questions or requests. I'm also posting frequent development reports so you can check what's coming up next.

*Disclaimer*: If it isn't obvious by now, I'm one of the TilemapKit developers. :)

Comment: TilemapKit is no more available for purchase [link](http://forum.tilemapkit.com/t/tilemapkit-development-is-on-hold/113) :(

Answer (score 25):

you should use JSTileMap that is designed to work with Sprite Kit

- add JSTileMap files to your project
- add libz.dylib to the linked frameworks and libraries section of your project
- import JSTileMap.h

and load a map with:

```
JSTileMap *tiledMap = [JSTileMap mapNamed:@"mapFileName.tmx"];
if (tiledMap) [mySKNode addChild:tiledMap];
```

Here is the source: https://github.com/slycrel/JSTileMap

Good Luck!!

Comment: JSTileMap does not support map downloaded from somewhere, otherwise it is awesome

Answer (score 2):

This is the best I have found.  I am not sure if the do-it-yourself method would work this instance as I haven't tried implementing it yet.

http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementation/parsing-tiled-tmx-format-maps-in-your-own-game-engine/